# Cannot connect to mysql 5.0.8 using mysql_connect with password

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

I can connect to my mysql db using php without a password fine. However, when I add a password in phpmyadmin I can no longer connect. I consistently get the error of:

```
"Could not connect: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

I've tried using both settings of MySQL password 4.0 and 4.1+ with the same results.

```
mysql_connect ("127.0.0.1", "admin", "password") or  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());;
mysql_select_db ("datatable");
```

Does anyone have an idea of what may be going on here?

EDIT: I can access it if I turn off the password. There seems to be some misunderstanding

Comment: Your password is incorrect. Make sure you typed it correctly, without leaving trailing spaces. Passwords are case sensitive.

Comment: I have tried doing this a few times already.

Comment: Are you sure you have an `admin` user account?

Comment: are you sure its admin and not root?

Comment: I think so. I can access everything fine if I remove the password from the account.

Comment: @user1330217 This means the `admin` account has no password.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can log in from the command line with these credentials?

Comment: Hmm, it seems like I can't access it through command line either. I think there's something funny happening when I set it in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

steps-

1. go to phpmyadmin;
2. click on the database you want to change the pw to (onl left);
3. click on "privileges";
4. click on the "edit privileges" icon on the right of the root user for localhost.
5. go to the "change password" block;
6. tick the "password" radio button;
7. enter password and re-type that password;
8. tick: ... keep the old one.
9. click "go";
10. now go open a MySql Console from the WAMPSERVER menu;
11. it will ask you for a pw – just hit the return since you don't have one yet (next time you go to the console you'll need to enter the new pw that you'r entering here). 
    type the following:

    UPDATE mysql.user 
    SET Password=PASSWORD("xxxxxx")
    WHERE User="root";
    (where xxxxxx is the password you entered in the previous step).
12. Now type: 
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
13. go to your WAMP or MAMP folder, find the APPS folder, and than click on your PHPMYADMIN folder ( e.g my folder called phpmyadmin2.11.6 ) and find the config.inc.php
14. open config.inc.php with wordpad and find the following text:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';`

now add the password that you used in step number 3 like this :

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourPasswordHere';`

1. now save this modification, and close config.inc.php

You should be all set now!

Source - http://www.knowledgesutra.com/discuss/tsilti-php-myadmin-access-mysql-database.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the mysql_connect statement you are showing, you are attempting to connect as `admin@'127.0.0.1'`. This demands the use of TCP/IP to connect to mysql. If you connect as `admin@localhost` this uses mysql.sock (the socket file) to connect to mysqld.

You should run this query

```
SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='admin';
```

You should see `admin@localhost` defined. You probably won't see `admin@'127.0.0.1'`. You could add it but it is easier to just code for `admin@localhost`.

Try changing your code as follows:

```
mysql_connect ("localhost", "admin", "password") or  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());;
mysql_select_db ("datatable");
```

If you can connect to mysql without a password, then your mysql installation is not secure.

You need to add a password to admin@localhost and remove anonymous user logins as follows:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET password=password('whateverpassword')
where user='admin' and host='localhost';
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Here is another suggestion: Create the admin@127.0.0.1 user like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO admin@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'whateverpassword';
```

and try your original code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your username or password are incorrect. Make sure you typed them correctly, without leaving trailing spaces. Usernames and passwords are case sensitive.

Comment: Are you sure the account name isn't the issue?

Comment: Yes, it definitely exists. I can connect to it if I remove the password.

Comment: @user1330217: If you can connect to it if you remove the password, it means the account has no password, and that's how you should log in to it. Don't try to enter a password that doesn't exist.

Comment: This is only if I remove the password from phpmyadmin as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you tamper with MySQL user data via phpMyAdmin you MUST execute the

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

command in order to make the new rules apply.